# How do I autoload aws.phar classes in the PHP command line?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to test my AWS credentials and no matter what I do I can't seem to get the AWS classes to load on the command line. Do I have to do something special to get AWS on the PHP CLI to work?

```
php > require('aws.phar');
php > use Aws\S3\S3Client;
php > $client = new S3Client(['version' => 'latest', 'region' => 'us-east-1']);

Warning: Uncaught Error: Class 'S3Client' not found in php shell code:1
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in php shell code on line 1
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP CLI does not support the `use` keyword. All classes must be referenced with their namespaces:

```
$client = new \Aws\S3\S3Client(['version' => 'latest', 'region' => 'us-east-1']);
```